# How to get checkbox append text using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="data[User][gender][]" id="UserGender1" value="1">Male
</label>
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="data[User][gender][]" id="UserGender2" value="2">Female
</label>
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="data[User][gender][]" id="UserGender3" value="3">Male and Female
</label>
```

There are 3 check-boxes now I want to both value `1`,`2`,`3` and the text `Male`,`Female`,`Male and Female`

I am using below code:

```
var con = "input[name='data[User][gender][]']:checked";   
var values = new Array();
//var tt = new Array();
$.each($(cond), function() {
    values.push($(this).val());
    //tt.push($(this).val().append());
});
```

But i want to get the text. How to get the text?

Comment: Could you consider wrapping the checkbox and the text in a <label>?

Comment: You'd be a lot better off adding a data-attribute or a label to the input because that text node is 'naked'

Comment: @Maurice Perry No when i am using <label> these 3 text are disabled

Comment: @learnphp: *"No when i am using <label> these 3 text are disabled"* That makes no sense. Putting them in a `label` does nothing to disable (or enable) them.

Comment: @learnphp: Your edit just now **completely changes the question**, invalidating [the previously-correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23564940/157247). I'm afraid that's just not cool. If you're going to completely change the basis of the question, make it a *new* question.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I have not changes anything just added <label>..</label>

Comment: @learnphp: *"I have not changes anything"* and *"...just added <label>...</label>..."* are contradictory statements. You changed the question **by** adding the labels. Earlier (see above!) you claimed you couldn't use labels. Well, which is it?

Comment: @learnphp: In any case, the correct answer is now correct a second time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update to this with `.nextSibling.nodeValue` to push in your `tt` array:

```
var con = "input[name='data[User][gender][]']:checked";
var tt = new Array(),
    values = [];
$.each($(con), function () {
    values.push($(this).val());
    tt.push(this.nextSibling.nodeValue);
});
console.log(tt);
```

If there's any possibility your checkboxes may not be followed by the text, you might make that `tt.push` more defensive:

```
tt.push(this.nextSibling ? this.nextSibling.nodeValue : "(missing text)");
```

---

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u6S57/)

---

As per your new edits you can change to this:

```
var con = "input[name='data[User][gender][]']:checked";
var tt = new Array(),
    values = [];
$.each($(con), function () {
    values.push($(this).val());
    tt.push($(this).closest('label').text());  //<----change this
});
console.log(tt);
```

Comment: Yup. nodeValue is what I thought too. And closing the tag is not really required.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - I began typing my answer before OP updated the question with `<label>` tags...

The text associated with each checkbox input should usually be encased in a `<label>` element, in either of the following ways. This also has the added benefit of allowing the checkbox to be checked/unchecked when clicking the label as well as the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="data[User][gender][]" id="UserGender1" value="1">
<label for="UserGender1">Male</label>
```

which can be targeted in jQuery like this:

```
var con = "input[name='data[User][gender][]']:checked";   
var values = new Array();
var tt = new Array();
$.each($(con), function() {
    values.push($(this).val());
    tt.push($("label[for='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']").html();
});
```

or alternatively:

```
<label for="UserGender1"><input type="checkbox" name="data[User][gender][]" id="UserGender1" value="1">Male</label>
```

which can be targeted in jQuery like this:

```
var con = "input[name='data[User][gender][]']:checked";   
var values = new Array();
var tt = new Array();
$.each($(con), function() {
    values.push($(this).val());
    tt.push($(this).parent().text());
});
```

Comment: That second example will include the markup of the checkbox. Really not what one wants...

Comment: You are right, I'll update my answer to `.text()` rather than `.html()`.